# MySQL table join indexes only working under certain conditions

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

have an odd one here. I've got a multi-table join query with correct indexes assigned for the join conditions. The query runs with the indexes when one of the tables is set as the primary join (.7sec complete), but not when another table is set(189sec complete). I'm hoping someone can help me understand why the index would be working in the second scenario but not in the first. I've included the join conditions below along with the EXPLAIN for each query:

Join Indexes Not Working:

```
        FROM
        ((
                `fuse`
                LEFT JOIN `occupancy` ON (((
                        CONVERT(substring_index(
                            `occupancy`.`last_name`,
                            '_',-(
                                1 
                            )),UNSIGNED INTEGER) = `fuse`.`agent_id` 
                    ) 
AND ( `fuse`.`login_date` = `occupancy`.`login_date` )))
                LEFT JOIN `reporting_match` ON ((
                        `fuse`.`agent_id` = `reporting_match`.`agent_id` 
                    )))
            )
```

[image]
Join Indexes Working:

```
    FROM
        ((
                `occupancy`
                LEFT JOIN `fuse` ON (((
                        CONVERT(substring_index(
                            `occupancy`.`last_name`,
                            '_',-(
                                1 
                            )),UNSIGNED INTEGER) = `fuse`.`agent_id` 
                    ) 
AND ( `fuse`.`login_date` = `occupancy`.`login_date` )))
                LEFT JOIN `reporting_match` ON (
                        substring_index(
                            `occupancy`.`last_name`,
                            '_',-(
                                1 
                            )) = `reporting_match`.`agent_id` 
                    ))
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe a side note: Normalize the schema and don't append an ID to a name. That function call to gain the ID from the name prevents index use for that condition.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example] i.e. at least the full DDL of the tables and the indexes. Also provide full queries, especially the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Thanks, no WHERE clauses in this query so nothing additional there. I think I'm just going to split out that ID in the name on import. Unfortunately I can't get a clean ID out of the system producing the data for that table, but I'd probably solve my problem by parsing that ID out.

Comment: I think it's the `LEFT JOIN` but I'm not sure. This might explain https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122856/191579

Comment: "full DDL" "indexes" "full queries" Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS What do "set as the primary join" & "table is set" mean? What is the difference between those queries?  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please format your code reasonably.

Comment: `a LEFT JOIN b` and `b LEFT JOIN a` are semantically different.  `LEFT JOIN` says that when a row in the 'right' table is missing, `NULLs` will be used.

Comment: Also, learn about "sargable".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, a bit tired when I posted this. I solved by removing the substring_index join condition in conjunction with appending the ID the substring was gathering to the occupancy table on data import. I then used that ID as the new join condition with the fuse table.